# Cannot read properties of undefined error when working with an API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data from an API which returns an array of objects in this format.

```
{Name: 'hitmonchan', Description: 'Fighting-type Pokémon introduced in Generation I'}
{Name: 'Gogoat', Description: 'A quadrupedal, hooved Pokémon similar to a goat'}... and so on
```

Here is what I am attempting to do. I fetch all the pokemons which is over 500, stuff them in an array called `allPokemons`. Then I want to do stuff with 4 random pokemons from the list. So I will have an array called `smallRandomPokemonArray` with only four pokemons chosen at random from the `allPokemon` array.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getallPokemons } from '../services/pokemonapi';

const empty_pokemon = {
    'Name': '',
    'Description': ''
}

function PokemonComponent() {


    const [allPokemons, setAllPokemons] = useState([]);
    const [smallRandomPokemonArray, setSmallRandomPokemonArray] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getAll();
    }, []);

    const getAll = () => {
        getallPokemons()
            .then(data => {

                //actual data with over 500 objects show in log
                console.log(data);
                setAllPokemons(data);
                randomChooser(data.length)
            })
    }

    const randomChooser = (length) => {
        let temporaryArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);

            //First Problem: this is returning index in numbers followed by undefined... why?
            console.log(randomIndex + " " + allPokemons[randomIndex]);
            temporaryArray.push(allPokemons[randomIndex]);

            //Second Problem: this is also returning "temp undefined"
            console.log("temp " + temporaryArray[i]);
        }
        setSmallRandomPokemonArray(temporaryArray);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="pokemondiv">
                {
                    smallRandomPokemonArray.map((element) => (
                        <div>
                            <p>{element.Name}</p>
                            <p>{element.Description}</p>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default PokemonComponent;
```

When I try to print values from the `setSmallRandomPokemonArray` I get that error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')
```

Also, please look at `First problem and Second problem` part in the code. They are also appearing as undefined in the console.log. From my understanding, it should work because `allPokemons` already exist when I start to randomize it. Then I just push four random values to the `smallRandomPokemonArray`. I dont know why its throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

You are calling `randomChooser(data.length)` just after `setAllPokemons(data);` in `getAll`. At this point `allPokemons` which is used inside `randomChooser` is still `[]`.

`emptyArray[0] == undefined`. `undefined.Name = Cannot read properties of undefined`. The takeaway is that when you call a `setState`, the related `state` is updated asynchronously. A re-render is needed to have the updated value.

## Solution

Change `getAll` to the code below, so its only job is to populate `allPokemons` state:

```js
const getAll = () => {
  getallPokemons().then((data) => {
    setAllPokemons(data);
  });
};
```

Then use an `useEffect` to get the four Pokemon you need:

```js
useEffect(() => {  
  /*
    I moved randomChooser here, so you don't have to put it in useEffect's 
    dependencies array, which if you do, you should wrap randomChooser in a 
    useCalback, as otherwise you get an infinite call.
  */
  const randomChooser = (length) => {
    const temporaryArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
      temporaryArray.push(allPokemons[randomIndex]);
    }
    setSmallRandomPokemonArray(temporaryArray);
  };
  if (allPokemons.length <= 0) return;
  randomChooser(allPokemons.length);
}, [allPokemons]);
```

## Another Solution

You could change `randomChooser` so that it receives the array, not its length:

```js
const randomChooser = (allPokemons) => {
  let temporaryArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allPokemons.length);
    temporaryArray.push(allPokemons[randomIndex]);
  }
  setSmallRandomPokemonArray(temporaryArray);
};
```

Then change `getAll` so you give data to `randomChooser`:

```js
const getAll = () => {
  getallPokemons().then((data) => {
    setAllPokemons(data);
    randomChooser(data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The `allPokemons` have not been set at the point where you are using it in `randomChooser`. react will set all state after the function finished running.
You need to pass the data into `randomChooser`.

```
 const randomChooser = (data) => {
    const length = data.length
    let temporaryArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);

        //First Problem: this is returning index in numbers followed by undefined... why?
        console.log(randomIndex + " " + data[randomIndex]);
        temporaryArray.push(data[randomIndex]);

        //Second Problem: this is also returning "temp undefined"
        console.log("temp " + temporaryArray[i]);
    }
    setSmallRandomPokemonArray(temporaryArray);
}
```